# Scaling home/enthusiast server setup

Tags: raid, samba, san, home-server

I'm looking to maintain a home server of media (videos,music,etc.) with some RAID(fallback or redundancy) support that I can update relatively easy over the years.

My high level plan is to buy 1U or 2U racks every year or so that have a lot of harddrive bays, and somehow link these logically (meaning I can treat all the space as one large disk I can connect to).

Is this possible? If so what kind of technologies do I need to use to link the separate computers in such a manner (and as efficient/fast as possible). If not, what other recommendations do you have for building a scaling home server (meaning I can add a few dozen TBs every 2-3 years).

Thanks

Comment: Rackmount equipment is typically intended to live in a data center, placing a higher priority on cooling than noise.  They may not be well-suited for a home server unless you have a suitable location away from where you'll be watching and listening to your media.

Comment: No worries on that, I have a home where this will be nestled in the basement! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like [Gluster](http://www.gluster.org/)?

Comment: Exactly the sort of solution/direction I was looking for thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [distributed filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems#Distributed_parallel_fault-tolerant_file_systems).

You'll end up with a slower filesystem (been reading about getting as low as 30% vs the real thing) but will be able to manage "virtual" drives as needed (have a look at the slides on [gluster.org](http://www.gluster.org/about/screen-shots/)).